# Using grepl to create a function for a dataframe

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
A            B
1            unicorn in the field
2            dog house in the yard
3            frog in the lake
4            house in the city
```

I am trying to create a new data frame using this data, if b has the word "House" or "Dog House". I have tried

```
dogdata<-which(df$B == grepl('house|dog house',df$B,ignore.case = TRUE)),A
```

So I want my outcome to be

```
A             B
2             dog house in the yard
4             house in the city
```

But I keep getting errors. Thank you

Comment: How about `df[which(grepl('house|dog house',df$B,ignore.case = TRUE)),]`

Comment: WOW! That worked. So simple! I knew I was close. Thank you so much! If you answer the question I will mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subset notation is a little bit off, and you actually don't need `which` at all:

```
df[grepl('house|dog house', df$B, ignore.case = TRUE),]
```

`grepl` returns a TRUE/FALSE vector, and we can subset with that.

Also, as an aside, to invert your selection (i.e. select rows that don't contain "house", or "dog house", you must use `!` and not `-`:

```
df[!grepl('house|dog house', df$B, ignore.case = TRUE),]
```

Comment: @Reagan no problem, also I just pulled out `which` because you don't need it.